# How to reorder the last six columns of a data frame in Julia without affecting the order of all other columns?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am working with Julia and I have a data frame with 160 columns and want to reorder the last six columns, from B,D,C,F,A,E to A,B,C,D,E,F.

I know I can do something like: df = df[[...,A,B,C,D,E,F]] but that requires that I type out all the previous columns as well. How can I avoid that?

Comment: You can also try `select(df, 1:ncol(df)-6, :A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F; copycols=false)`. The `copycols` means the resulting DataFrame will share the memory and change together with original DataFrame. The benefit is increased performance.

Comment: The combination of range and column list is I think shortest. The alternative is e.g. to use `Not` (if you want to be explicit about the columns), eg. `select(df, Not(x), x)` where `x` is a vector of columns to put at the end of data frame (along with their order).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the names function to get the column names of a `dataframe`.
Then, you can use array indexing to reorder the columns without affecting the order of the other columns.

```
column_names = names(df)
last_six_columns = column_names[end-5:end]
reordered_columns = [setdiff(column_names, last_six_columns); last_six_columns]
df_reordered = df[:,reordered_columns]
```

- `column_names` stores the names of all the columns in the data frame.
- `last_six_columns` is an array containing the names of the last six columns in the desired order.
- `reordered_columns` combines the remaining columns (excluding the last six) with the last six columns in the desired order.
- `df_reordered` is a new data frame with the columns reordered as specified.

> By this, you don't need to explicitly type out all the previous columns.

or

```
column_names = names(df)
new_order = vcat(column_names[1:end-6], [:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F])
select!(df, new_order)
```

Comment: This seems great, thanks! However, when executing the very last line I receive the error: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::DataFrame, ::Vector{String}). Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: This one worked for me: `df = df[:,reordered_columns]` Thanks a lot for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

To build on @bajju's answer:

```
cols = names(df)
df = df[:, vcat(cols[1:end-5], sort(cols[end-6:end]))]
```